# Find unique field values in ElasticSearch using Spring Data ElasticsearchRepository

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an interface extending ElasticsearchRepository and have successfully created methods to search such as:

`Page<AuditResult> findByCustomerCodeAndHost(String customerCode, String host, Pageable pageable);`

Now, I want an endpoint to hit that would return me all of the possible host values for that customerCode so that I can build a dropdown list in my front end to select a value to send to that findByCustomerCodeAndHost endpoint, something like:

`List<String> findUniqueHostByCustomerCode(String customerCode)`

Is this even possible using an ElasticsearchRepository?

I know there is the Distinct keyword I can use like
`List<String> findDistinctByCustomerCode(String customerCode);` but this doesn't let me specify the host field.

---

Edit:
Here is how I accomplished what I wanted but as it is not currently possible to actually do this with ElasticsearchRepository it isn't an actual "answer".

I created a Spring web `@RestController` class that I exposed a `@GetMapping` REST endpoint that executed an aggregation query.

The query in kibana console:

```
GET auditresult/_search
{
  "size": "0",
  "aggs" : {
    "uniq_custCode" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "customerCode", "include": "<CUSTOMER_CODE>" },
        "aggs" : {
          "uniq_host" : {
           "terms" : { "field" : "host"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And, based off this question [ElasticSearch aggregation with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985767/elasticsearch-aggregation-with-java) I came up with

```
@GetMapping("/hosts/{customerCode}")
String getHostsByCustomer(@PathVariable String customerCode) {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("auditresult");
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder().size(0);
    IncludeExclude ie = new IncludeExclude(customerCode, "");
    TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation =
            AggregationBuilders
                    .terms("uniq_custCode").includeExclude(ie)
                    .field("customerCode")
                    .subAggregation(
                            AggregationBuilders
                                    .terms("uniq_host")
                                    .field("host")
                    );
    searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(aggregation);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    try {
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        Terms cust = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("uniq_custCode");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{\"hosts\":[");
        for (Terms.Bucket bucket : cust.getBuckets()) {
            Terms hosts = bucket.getAggregations().get("uniq_hosts");
            for (Terms.Bucket host : hosts.getBuckets()) {
                System.out.println(host.getKey());
                sb.append("\"" + host.getKey() + "\",");
            }
        }
        String out = sb.toString();
        out = out.substring(0, out.length() - 1);
        return out + "]}";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "{\"hosts\":[]}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you would need here is something Spring Data calls projections, for Spring Data MongoDB you can [read the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections) to see how it works there.

Alas this is not implemented in Spring Data Elasticsearch (yet), I created [an issue in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-805) for this.