# ElasticSearch Java API Client 7.16 Structuring Aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "my-agg-name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my-field"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my-sub-agg-name": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "my-other-field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to perform the above elastic search query in java using the new elasticsearch java api client . I am using elastic search version 7.16 . Can someone please help me in building the same query using the new elasticsearch java api client .

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985767/elasticsearch-aggregation-with-java

Comment: That uses the older version of Java client .

Answer (score 0):

Here's one you can try:

```
SearchResponse<YourClass> response = client.search(b -> b
                .index("your_index")                 
                .aggregations("first_agg",a->a.terms(t->t.field("my_field"))
                 .aggregations("sub_agg", s->s.avg(av->av.field("other_field")))),
                YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Doesnt this just create 2 separate aggregations ? 
Did you ever get this working Arun ?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 (recommended)**

make sure to import:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.dsl.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.dsl.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
```

then inside your code write this:

```
// Construct the search request    
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("your_index");

searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder -> sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()) // Add a query to match all documents
        .aggregations(aggregationBuilder -> aggregationBuilder
        .terms("my-agg-name", term -> term.field("my-field")) // Add an aggregation named "my-agg-name" of type terms to group documents by the value of "my-field"
        // Now we have a number of groups and we will add the sub-aggregation to them
        .aggregations(subAggregationBuilder -> subAggregationBuilder
        .avg("my-sub-agg-name", avg -> avg.field("my-other-field"))))); // Add a sub-aggregation named "my-sub-agg-name" of type avg to calculate the average of "my-other-field"

// Execute the search request and retrieve the search response
SearchResponse<Void> searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);//assuming that you already defined a client

// You can handle the search response by using it directly
System.out.println(searchResponse);
```

**Method 2 (not recommended)**

I will share another method it is not recommended but useful if you can't do your code using the java-client, you still can use your basic query by:

```
// Define your query, for example in your case the aggregation will be
String query = "{\n" +
            "  \"aggs\": {\n" +
            "    \"my-agg-name\": {\n" +
            "      \"terms\": {\n" +
            "        \"field\": \"my-field\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"aggs\": {\n" +
            "        \"my-sub-agg-name\": {\n" +
            "          \"avg\": {\n" +
            "            \"field\": \"my-other-field\"\n" +
            "          }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

// Create the request
Request request = new Request("POST", "/your_index/_search");

// Add your query to the request
request.setJsonEntity(query);

// Execute the request
Response response = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);

// This will print JSON file that has all the data, it will look like the Elasticsearch response exactly
System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent());

// You can extract the average by parsing the JSON response
```